# order paths by length in embedded database neo4j

Tags: neo4j, traversal

How can we retrieve all simple path between two nodes in a graph, with the paths sorted by length. There is an order by clause in the Cypher query but I am not able to find anything similar in the java apis for the embedded database.

Is there a method or do I have to sort them myself after retrieving the paths?

Comment: you can always run the cypher query directly from java code.

Comment: thanks Sumeet, that is an option. I wanted to be sure if the functionality is there in Java before going for the Cypher approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neo4j has a Java API package for graph algorithms to do exactly the operation you've asked for. See the below code snippet to see how it works.

For more insight, see the [reference manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/graph-algo.html) and the [javadocs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.3/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphalgo/GraphAlgoFactory.html). The snippet below is written in groovy and is available [here as well](https://gist.github.com/95b5310f061f9f1c40a3):

```
@Grab(group="org.neo4j", module="neo4j-cypher", version="2.1.3")
@Grab(group="org.neo4j", module="neo4j-lucene-index", version="2.1.3")
@Grab(group='org.neo4j', module='neo4j-graph-algo', version='2.1.3')

import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory
import org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpander
import org.neo4j.graphdb.PathExpanders
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Path
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node
import org.neo4j.graphdb.DynamicLabel
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.GraphAlgoFactory
import org.neo4j.graphalgo.PathFinder
import org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorUtil
import org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine

def db = new GraphDatabaseFactory()
  .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("graph.db")
  .newGraphDatabase()

def ee = new ExecutionEngine(db)
ee.execute("""
create (a:myLabel {myprop:'a'}),
(b:myLabel {myprop:'b'}),
(c:myLabel {myprop:'c'}),
(d:myLabel {myprop:'d'}),
(a)-[:KNOWS]->(b),
(a)-[:KNOWS]->(c),
(c)-[:KNOWS]->(b),
(c)-[:KNOWS]->(e),
(d)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
""")

def tx = db.beginTx()
try {

  // lookup start and end node
  Label label = DynamicLabel.label("myLabel")
  Node startNode = IteratorUtil.single(db.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(label, "myprop", "a"))
  Node endNode = IteratorUtil.single(db.findNodesByLabelAndProperty(label, "myprop", "b"))

  PathExpander pathExpander = PathExpanders.allTypesAndDirections() // adopt to your needs
  def maxDepth = 5 // adopt to your needs

  PathFinder<Path> pathFinder = GraphAlgoFactory.allSimplePaths(pathExpander, maxDepth)
  Iterable<Path> result = pathFinder.findAllPaths(startNode, endNode)

  // sort the results, in java this is more effort ;-)
  List<Path> sortedResult = result.sort { it.length() }

  for (Path p: sortedResult) {
      println p
  }
  tx.success()
} finally {
   tx.finish()
}

db.shutdown()
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I used similar in java to sort the paths on path lengths.